# JournalRecord-Hook under Windows 10

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have a big - at the moment unsolvable - problem with JournalRecord-Hook under Windows 10.

16 years ago I wrote a Macro-Recorder. It is downloadable as Freeware and is used by many people.

It is a 32 bit program, written in Delphi 6.

The main lines of the problem are:

```
CONST HookHandleRecord : HHook = 0;
      JournalRecordProcCalled : boolean = false;

Function JournalRecordProc(Code:integer;wp:wParam;lp:lParam):integer; StdCall;
VAR f : Text;
Begin
if not JournalRecordProcCalled 
   then begin JournalRecordProcCalled:=true;
              assign(f,'JournalRecordProc.txt');Rewrite(f);writeln(f,HookHandleRecord);close(f)
        end;      
Result:=CallNextHookEx(HookHandleRecord,Code,wp,lp)
End;

Procedure Record_Macro; StdCall;
VAR Terminate : double;
f : Text;
Begin
HookHandleRecord:=SetWindowsHookEx(wh_JournalRecord,@JournalRecordProc,hInstance,0);
assign(f,'H:\HookHandleRecord.txt');Rewrite(f);
writeln(f,HookHandleRecord);close(f);
Terminate:=GetTickCount+2000;
repeat Sleep(100);Application.ProcessMessages;
until GetTickCount>=Terminate;
UnhookWindowsHookEx(HookHandleRecord);
Windows.Beep(5000,200);
End;
```

In all Windows versions "HookHandleRecord" is valid Result. In Windows 10 the system hangs between "SetWindowsHookEx" and "UnhookWindowsHookEx" and "JournalRecordProc" is never called.

In all other Windows Versions the code runs without problems.

The JournalRecordProc and the call of `SetWindowsHookEx` are located in a DLL.

The program and the DLLs are digitaly signed with a valid Comodo signature, which is assigned to my name.

A Manifest file with `level="requireAdministrator"` and `uiAccess="true"` is included in the Exe and the Dlls.

UAC is disabled.

The program is started with administrator privileges from the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Makro".

Thank you for help!

Comment: So why did you add C++ tag?

Comment: Can't you post your `JournalRecordProc`? What if your hook procedure just calls `CallNextHookEx(..)` to pass it on?

Comment: We can't debug code we can't even see. Use the debugger to try and sort it out.